# Gaussian Integrals on Complex Plane

Tags: integration, complex-numbers, gaussian-integral

I am having some difficulty doing integrals like

$$ \int_{-\infty}^\infty e^{2|\alpha - \gamma|^2} e^{-|\gamma|^2/\mu} d^2\gamma $$

where $\alpha$ and $\gamma$ are complex numbers, $\mu$ is real, and $d^2\gamma = d\text{Re}(\alpha)\,d\text{Im}(\alpha)$ up to a factor of $\pi$. I see that this is some kind of Gaussian integral and I expect (and hope) to get a Gaussian out.

My question is: should I be doing this integral by writing $\alpha$ and $\gamma$ in terms of real and imaginary parts, and working from there, or is there an easier way to do it?

If somebody could point me to a resource that discusses integrals like the above, or show an easier way to do this integral, that would be appreciated.

Comment: Maybe an example would help?

Comment: Sorry, are you asking me for another example of the kinds of integrals I'm looking at, or stating that a worked example might be helpful for my understanding (which it definitely would)?

Comment: Well, it seems that you've written a general expression for some type of "Gaussian integral".  Might be nice to see a specific example, and even some motivation (where does it occur).

Comment: Anyway, looking at it again, probabably it would be straightforward to evaluate in terms of the real and imaginary parts (since you essentially have $\int \int \text{Gaussian integrand} \, dx\,dy.)$

Comment: Ah, I see. I had been thinking about this integral as a specific example. This particular integral, and some others like it, came up for me in the context of phase space representations of quantum states. I could try to do it as you describe, I was just wondering if there was any easier way. Maybe I've just become a wimp since entering grad school, sticking everything in Mathematica!

Comment: Yes, *Mathematica* is a nice tool, but it would be best to verify its output whenever you can.

Comment: [Closely related](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gaussian_integral#n-dimensional_with_linear_term).